# confused by some Python grammar

Tags: python

Could anyone help to clarify what means `(i,)` here?

```
def combinationSum2(self, candidates, target):
    candidates.sort()
    table = [None] + [set() for i in range(target)]
    for i in candidates:
        if i > target:
            break
        for j in range(target - i, 0, -1):
            table[i + j] |= {elt + (i,) for elt in table[j]}
        table[i].add((i,))
    return map(list, table[target])
```

Comment: I am also confused by  `[None] + [set() for i in range(target)]`, does it add two list? And how set() functions here? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks Martijn, the reference is very helpful. If you could add an answer, I will mark it as answered to benefit other members of SO. :)